# How to fix 'driver.page_source is not returning the current DOM from the browser'?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium to interact with a browser, and for this page the driver.page_source is different from what I see in browser.

Furthermore, I am unable to find a specific div by x_path, even though i know its id and x_path from Chrome.

Things I have tried
- driver.refresh()
- driver.find_elements_by_xpath()
- driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("react-root")')
- driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

I have read several articles online, and have identified the potential for a discrepancy between driver.page_source and the actual browser DOM.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.heddels.com/sale-finder/')

time.sleep(10)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('html/body')
element.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div[2]/input)

'react-root' in driver.page_source
```

I expect for the driver to find the element, but it fails to, and when examining the page source it is not capturing anything on screen.

Comment: xpath - html/body is returning 7 elements. It has be unique. try unique xpath -/html/body[contains(@class,'page_sale-finder')]

Comment: use the browser's inspector to view the current page source.  (right-click on element and choose, "inspect")  For items which are created via javascript, you will probably want to use a WebDriverWait to wait for an ExpectedCondition to evaluate to true.

Comment: @Sureshmani the issue is that sale-finder is not unique to the page nor is it what I need to engage with. I am looking to get the search bar, or the anything represented in the DOM.

Comment: @pcalkins I have used inspect previously to get the exact x_path and even that does not work. The x_path is not returning as existing

Comment: `page_source` is not even used in the example code

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, sorry I just added it. When i search page source or use find_by_xpath they both fail to yield what i want which is what I can see in my browser

Comment: are you waiting long enough for the javascript to render?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I have tried checking intermittently to see if it changes, but it does not. As of now, I enter the website, wait, click escape on the popup, and then check the source